# Go and colors in console

Tags: go, command-line-interface

How can I make my Go program print colored text in the console without using external libraries?

I've tried:

```golang
fmt.Print("\033[33m"+mystring)
```

But it's not producing any color.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/fatih/color. You can learn from reading the source.

Comment: I'm new to Go so trying to understand that is a mission for me. Still doesn't answer my question but, I'll try looking through it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: «I've adding "`\033[33m`" in front of my string still no color.» is not an actionable statement: I certainly know of a way to have those characters "in front of a string" in a way they won't be interpreted as ANSI escape codes affecting to control the terminal regarding the colors. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please update your question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: …Also be sure to include the details about your environment: say, those ANSI control code won't work on stock consoles shipped with Windows (nether `cmd.exe` nor PS).

Answer (score 8):

What you can do is study the source code of this library as suggested out by @jub0bs already. It is pretty easy to follow.

This code prints hello in blue.

I got 34 from [here](https://github.com/fatih/color/blob/f4c431696a22e834b83444f720bd144b2dbbccff/color.go#L67) and `Sprintf` from [here](https://github.com/fatih/color/blob/f4c431696a22e834b83444f720bd144b2dbbccff/color_test.go#L48)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    colored := fmt.Sprintf("\x1b[%dm%s\x1b[0m", 34, "Hello")
    fmt.Println(colored)
}
```